# Python Development in multiple repositories

Tags: python, git, pip, setuptools, microservices

We are trying to find the best way to approach that problem.
Say I work in a Python environment, with pip & setuptools.
I work in a normal git flow, or so I hope.
So:

1. Move to feature branch in some app, make changes.
2. Move to feature branch in a dependent lib - Develop thing.
3. Point the app, using "-e git+ssh" to the feature branch of the dependent lib.
4. Create a Pull Request.

When this is all done, I want to merge stuff to master, but I can't without making yet another final change to have the app (step 3 above) requirements.txt now point to the main branch of the feature.

Is there any good workflow for "micro services" or multiple dependent source codes in python that we are missing?

Comment: Try to tell us a bit more about your expectations from the solution. You have described some steps, but it is not clear, what you expect as a result. Is your question really relevant to microservices? Do you release python packages?

Comment: @JanVlcinsky Good point. The release is not a package. It's a simple Pyramid web app with internal libraries we use (on top of pypi devs). My end goal is to be able to "merge" the changes without any additional changes to the code. e.g. merge as is to master branch.

Comment: @JARJARbeans If you care about pushing modified code to master without having to do manual merge, then you shall use `git rebase` which before you push the changes pulls the latest master content, replays locally done feature changes and push it to master, which accept them as fast forward changes. Is this the answer? One [git rebase blog entry is here](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/09/14/dont-be-scared-of-git-rebase/)

Comment: @JanVlcinsky Sorry. no. Rebase is not so much relevant. Git a side. the issue is with two different source codes that contains API breaking changes. I updated the lib, on some feature branch. I than updated the main app with the code, pointing to the *lib on the feature branch*. Once this is reviewed I need to merge lib to master + update the app code to now point to *lib on master*. Hopefully this makes more sense..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using git dependencies and not devpi.
I think when git is used, there is no need to add another package repository as long as pip can use this.

The core issue, where the branch code (because of a second level dependency) is different from the one merged to master is not solved yet, instead we work around that by working to remove that second level dependency.

Answer (score 1):

## Python application workflow from development to deployment

It looks like you are in search for developing Python application, using git.

Following description is applicable to any kind of Python based application,
not only to `Pyramid` based web ones.

### Requirements

Situation:

- developing Python based solution using Pyramid web framework
- there are multiple python packages, participating in final solution, packages might be dependent.
- some packages come from public pypi, others might be private ones
- source code controlled by git

Expectation:

- proposed working style shall allow:

  - pull requests
  - shall work for situations, where packages are dependent
- make sure, deployments are repeatable

### Proposed solution

Concepts:

- even the Pyramid application released as versioned package
- for private pypi use `devpi-server` incl. volatile and release indexes.
- for package creation, use `pbr`
- use `tox` for package unit testing
- test, before you release new package version
- test, before you deploy
- keep deployment configuration separate form application package

#### Pyramid web app as a package

Pyramid allows creation of applications in form of Python package. In
fact, whole initial tutorial (containing 21 stages) is using exactly this
approach.

Despite the fact, you can run the application in develop mode, you do not have
to do so in production.  Running from released package is easy.

Pyramid uses nice `.ini` configuration files. Keep `development.ini` in the
package repository, as it is integral part for development.

On the other hand, make sure, production `.ini` files are not present as they
should not mix with application and belong to deployment stuff.

To make deployment easier, add into your package a command, which prints to
stdout typical deployment configuration. Name the script e.g. `myapp_gen_ini`.

Write unittests and configure `tox.ini` to run them.

#### Keep deployment stuff separate from application

Mixing application code with deployment configurations will make problem at
the moment, you will have to install to second instance (as you are likely to
change at least one line of your configuration).

In deployment repository:

- keep here `requirements.txt`, which lists the application package and other
  packages needed for production. Be sure you specify exact package version at
  least for your application package.
- keep here `production.ini` file. If you have more deployments, use one branch per deployment.
- put here `tox.ini`

`tox.ini` shall have following content:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27
# use py34 or others, if your prefer

[testenv]
commands = 
deps =
    -rrequirements.txt
```

Expected use of deployment respository is:

1. clone it to the server
2. run `tox`, this will create virtualenv `.tox/py27`
3. activate the virtualenv by `$ source .tox/py27/bin/activate`
4. if `production.ini` does not exist in the repo yet, run command
   `$ myapp_gen_ini > production.ini` to generate template for production
   configuration
5. edit the `production.ini` as needed.
6. test, it works.
7. commit the `production.ini` changes to the repository
8. do other stuff needed to deploy the app (configure web server, supervisord etc.)

#### For `setup.py` use `pbr` package

To make package creation simpler, and to keep package versioning related to git
repository tags, use `pbr`. You will end up with `setup.py` being only 3 lines
long and all relevant stuff will be specified in `setup.cfg` in form of ini
file.

Before you build the first time, you have to have some files in git repository,
otherwise it will complain. As you use git, this shall be no problem.

To assign new package version, set `$ git tag -a 0.2.0` and build it. This will
create the package with version `0.2.0`.

As a bonus, it will create `AUTHORS` and `ChangeLog` based on your commit
messages. Keep these files in `.gitignore` and use them to create `AUTHORS.rst`
and `ChangeLog.rst` manually (based on autogenerated content).

When you push your commits to another git repository, do not forget to push the tags too.

#### Use `devpi-server` as private pypi

`devpi-server` is excellent private pypi, which will bring you following advantages:

- having private pypi at all
- cached public pypi packages
- faster builds of virtual environments (as it will install from cached packages)
- being able to use `pip` even without having internet connectivity
- pushing between various types of package indexes: one for development
  (published version can change here), one for deployment (released version will not change here).
- simple unit test run for anyone having access to it, and it will even collect
  the results and make them visible via web page.

For described workflow it will contribute as repository of python packages, which can be deployed.

Command to use will be:

- `$ devpi upload` to upload developed package to the server
- `$ devpi test <package_name>` to download, install, run unit test,
  publish test results to devpi-server and clean up temporary installation.
- `$ devpi push ...` to push released package to proper index on `devpi-server` or even on public pypi.

Note, that all the time it is easy to have `pip` command configured to consume
packages from selected index on `devpi` server for `$ pip install <package>`.

`devpi-server` is also ready for use in continuous integration testing.

#### How `git` fits into this workflow

Described workflow is not bound to particular style of using `git`.

On the other hand, `git` can play it's role in following situations:

- `commit`: commit message will be part of autogenerated `ChangeLog`
- `tag`: defines versions (recognized by `setup.py` based on `pbr`).

As `git` is distributed, having multiple repositories, branches etc.,
`devpi-server` allows similar distribution as each user can have it's own
working index to publish to. Anyway, finally there will be one `git` repository
with `master` branch to use. In `devpi-server` will be also one agreed
production index.

## Summary

Described process is not simple, but the complexity is relevant to complexity of the task.

It is based on tools:

- `tox`
- `devpi-server`
- `pbr` (Python package)
- `git`

Proposed solution allows:

- managing python packages incl. release management
- unit testing and continuous integration testing
- any style of using `git`
- deployment and development having clearly defined scopes and interactions.

Your question assumes multiple repositories. Proposed solution allows decoupling multiple repositories by means of well managed package versions, published to devpi-server.

Comment: Thanks Jan. I appreciate the through and end-to-end type of response. That being said, I am not sure I understand how this answers the particular question I had in mind. Unless I miss something the issue will be the same. Developer will build his stuff, pushing to devpi a lib with a certain version, on his index. Than change stuff in the main app, pointing to that version + code changes. Once this needs to be merged to master, he actually needs to push the lib again to dev-api, and add yet another extra commit that points to the dev-pi version that is not his index. so same issue applies here.